# EditText for filtering/searching listView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, search, filter

I am new to programming and with help of a tutorial i created an application, where you can create shelfs and store these in a sqlite database. With help of a listview the shelfs will be displayed. Now I set an EditText on Top of the ListView and with stackoverflow I tried to implement a "dynamic filtering". I thought this would be possible with the "addTextChangedListener" but it didnt work at all. I tried almost 10 different methods and 4 different other tutorials, spent day and almost nights by trying but nothing worked. Hopefully you guys can help me.

thanks

Following my Code of the DataListActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.kasutwentyseven.gui4selfshelf.R;
import com.kasutwentyseven.gui4selfshelf.Scans.ScanActivity;

public class DataListActivity extends Activity {
public ListView listView;
public SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
public ShelfDBHelper shelfDBHelper;
public Cursor cursor;
public EditText inputSearch;
public ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter; //DataSource - Adapter

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);

    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Lobster.ttf");
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_yourshelfs);
    myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout); //ArrayAdapter

    inputSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_search_shelf);


    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            listDataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
    });

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScanActivity.class);
            n.putExtra("postition", position);
            startActivity(n);

shelfDBHelper = new ShelfDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = shelfDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = shelfDBHelper.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String name;

            name = cursor.getString(0);

            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(name);
            listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


}
```

And the Code of my Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.kasutwentyseven.gui4selfshelf.R;

import java.sql.SQLDataException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
private List list= new ArrayList();
private static final String TAG = "Shelf ADAPTER";
private ShelfDBHelper shelfDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}
static class LayoutHandler
{
    TextView NAME;
}
@Override
public void add(Object object){
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}
@Override
public int getCount(){
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position){
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.NAME = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_shelf_name);
        row.setTag(layoutHandler);
    }else{
        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();

    }

    DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.NAME.setText(dataProvider.getName());

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library
https://github.com/edsilfer/custom-searchable
,it does what you want and additionally it brings nice animations to your app.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a custom adapter you need to implement the filter in it. The approach you took that is for android default adapter.

The code for custom filter is

```
public class SearchableAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private List<String>originalData = null;
private List<String>filteredData = null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

public SearchableAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
    this.filteredData = data ;
    this.originalData = data ;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unnecessary calls
    // to findViewById() on each row.
    ViewHolder holder;

    // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
    // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
    // by ListView is null.
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
        // we want to bind data to.
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
        // and the ImageView.
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // If weren't re-ordering this you could rely on what you set last time
    holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<String> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString ;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
}
```

The code is taken from  https://gist.github.com/fjfish/3024308 here. You can see a complete reference here too.

Comment: So, do I have to edit my Adapterclass or do I have to set up a new SearchAdapterclass ?

Comment: I copied your SearchableAdapter code and made some configurations. But now I get an error @ my DatalistActivtiy
@  cursor = shelfDBHelper.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name;

                name = cursor.getString(0);

                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(name);
                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

@ the line listDataAdaptder.add(dataProvider);   //the add is red

It says: Cannot resolve method add